# Setup webpack so import 'assets/styles.scss' will load generated css from diffrent domain

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack-4

I'm creating a widget that will be loaded by third party websites via javascript file.

This js file will be build with webpack. It is ts based app and in some places I need to import some assets like css, images etc...

How to configure webpack so when there will be for example such code

```
import 'assets/styles.scss';
```

then it will know to fetch it from home domain like `my-widget.com/assets/styles.css` instead of `assets/styles.css`

The same question to other assets like images etc...

Is this possible?

My build folder looks like this:

```
build/assets/styles.css
build/lib.js
```

So when `lib.js` is loaded from where it is hosted e.g `my-widget.com/index.html` then styles are loaded correctly.

But when third party website like `foo.com` will try to load it using `<script src="https://my-widget.com/lib.js"></script>` then styles are not loaded.

Comment: `.css` files can be linked externally, but `.scss` would have to be fetched by webpack and included in the compilation. Is this question about the former or the latter? Or both?

Comment: I have scss that are converted to css and it is putted to build folder so I have /build/assets/styles.css in the output and my library file is in /build/lib.js. Now this library is available publicaly but when thirdparty website is using this library there is no styles but when working from my-widget.com styles are working fine.

Comment: just per chance are you importing with full url with https://whatever.com/whatever.css or with relative url. Seems to me from face value its network issue rather then parser issue.  check the dev consle network tab on other domain hard reload and see the response code for the file. was it attempted fetch at all or was it got where, it will certainly show where it fetched it from.